# Boolean variable does not insert | PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.10

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

first of all, apologies for my bad english.

I try to set two vars as booleans, like this:

```
if ((strlen($imgCropperIPS) > 100) || (file_exists('files/'.$idIPS .'_ips.jpg'))) {
    $logoIPS_temp = true;
} else {
    $logoIPS_temp = false;
}

if ((strlen($imgCropperEmp) > 100) || (file_exists('files/'.$idIPS .'_emp.jpg'))) {
    $logoEmp_temp = true;
} else {
    $logoEmp_temp = false;
}
$data['logoBool'] = $logoEmp_temp . "-" . $logoIPS_temp;
$query = "UPDATE ips SET ipsName='$nameIPS', ipsNIT='$nitIPS', externalMant=$externalMant, empName='$nameEmp', empNIT='$nitEmp', ipsLogo= $logoIPS_temp, empLogo = $logoEmp_temp WHERE idIPS = '$idIPS' AND userAdmin='$userAdmin'";
    $data['query'] = $query;
```

The server response this:

```
data['logoBool'] response: "-1"

data['query'] response:

"UPDATE ips SET ipsName='hospital', ipsNIT='848484', externalMant=true, empName='buss', empNIT='12312312', ipsLogo= 1, empLogo =  WHERE idIPS = '1' AND userAdmin='1'"
```

The problem is with two vars "logoEmp_temp and logoIPS_temp"

Help.

Define vars in the start of document...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
    $temp_ips = "false";
    $temp_emp = "false";

    if ((strlen($imgCropperIPS) > 100) || (file_exists('files/'.$idIPS .'_ips.jpg'))) {
        $temp_ips = "true";
    } else {
        $temp_ips= "false";
    }

    if ((strlen($imgCropperEmp) > 100) || (file_exists('files/'.$idIPS .'_emp.jpg'))) {
        $temp_emp = "true";
    } else {
        $temp_emp = "false";
    }
```

Comment: I am struggling to see how that fixed the problem, which isn't clear in the first place.

Comment: set bool vars as string